# Looping twice over a string:

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay so I was writing this code to **identify number of 8 present in the range 0, 889.** Every time I run this code I get value 241 and that is wrong. The for loop iterates over the value and the moment it finds 8 it appends the value. But, their are numbers like 881, 888. **It doesn't look forward and append the second or the third 8. How do I solve this or reiterate over it again.**

```
temp = [] # Contains number with 8 in it.
for i in range(0, 889):
     if '8' in str(i):
         r_temp.append(i)
            
print(temp)
values = [] # Takes in the 8 in the integer
i = '8'
for z in r_temp:
    if i in str(z):
        values.append(i)
```

Comment: Where do you see a count?

Comment: There is nothing in this code that prints 241

Comment: There to nothing in this code that attempts to inspect the numbers beyond the occurrence of 8

Comment: What is `r_temp`? Should that be `temp`?

Answer (score 0):

the text.count('pattern') method can be used here:

```
total_count = 0
# loop from 0 ... 889
for number in range(0, 889):
     # convert the integer to a string
     number_as_string = str(number)
     # get the number of '8' in the string
     count_of_8_in_str = number_as_string.count('8')
     # sum up 
     total_count = total_count + count_of_8_in_str
print(total_count)
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the number of time `8` occurs in the str, using `list-comprehension`:

```
print(sum([str(x).count('8') for x in range(0,889)]))
```